# How to focus/click button when my other function call?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

I am having angular js script, Here my page is load first time then focus is on button, Now problem is that 1) First time,when my ng-change function called then focus is goes to that button 2) second time also its working well 3) but third time its not working. That Means focus not set to button or button not clicked.

```
// This is my function which is called when ng-model value changed
 $scope.checkEneteredQuantity = function(qty,bagProduct,index){
      if(qty == 0){
        bagProduct.count = 1;
      }else{
      var qty = parseInt(qty);
      var nwqt = parseInt(qty); 
      var myflag = 0;
      if(qty > 0){

        myflag = 1;

      }else if(qty < 0){
        myflag = 2;
      }
      if(myflag == 1){
        if(bagProduct.return == "simple"){
           var cal = parseFloat(bagProduct.count * bagProduct.priceAftertax)
           if ((cal % 1) != 0){ 
            if(cal.toString().split(".")[1].length > 2){
              bagProduct.newpric = parseFloat(cal).toFixed(2);
            }else{
              bagProduct.newpric = cal;
            }
        }else{
            bagProduct.newpric = cal;
        }


        $("#output-text-bulk").click();// this is not working
    }
```

//This is my button code

```
 <button id="output-text-bulk" numeric-keyboard-input="" ng-model="simple"
         ng-bind="simple" style="padding: 10px;">
 </button>
```

// This is my function which is called when ng-model value changed

```
 $scope.checkEneteredQuantity = function(qty,bagProduct,index){
      if(qty == 0){
        bagProduct.count = 1;
      }else{
      var qty = parseInt(qty);
      var nwqt = parseInt(qty); 
      var myflag = 0;
      if(qty > 0){

        myflag = 1;

      }else if(qty < 0){
        myflag = 2;
      }
      if(myflag == 1){
        if(bagProduct.return == "simple"){
           var cal = parseFloat(bagProduct.count * bagProduct.priceAftertax)
           if ((cal % 1) != 0){ 
            if(cal.toString().split(".")[1].length > 2){
              bagProduct.newpric = parseFloat(cal).toFixed(2);
            }else{
              bagProduct.newpric = cal;
            }
        }else{
            bagProduct.newpric = cal;
        }


        $("#output-text-bulk").click();// this is not working
    }
```

i want to set focus on button when my ng-change function called.

Comment: can you provide a working demo of your code so that I can run it here on so? just edit your question and while in the editor press ctrl+m and a code editor will popup. paste your code there

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should get out your focus code from all scope, then every time run your change function focus code is run and your button is clickable, or check your condition (if/else)

```
$scope.checkEneteredQuantity = function (qty, bagProduct, index) {
    if (qty == 0) {
        bagProduct.count = 1;
    } else {
        var qty = parseInt(qty);
        var nwqt = parseInt(qty);
        var myflag = 0;
        if (qty > 0) {
            myflag = 1;
        } else if (qty < 0) {
            myflag = 2;
        }
        if (myflag == 1) {
            if (bagProduct.return == "simple") {
                var cal = parseFloat(bagProduct.count * bagProduct.priceAftertax)
                if ((cal % 1) != 0) {
                    if (cal.toString().split(".")[1].length > 2) {
                        bagProduct.newpric = parseFloat(cal).toFixed(2);
                    } else {
                        bagProduct.newpric = cal;
                    }
                } else {
                    bagProduct.newpric = cal;
                }
                //$("#output-text-bulk").click();// this is not working
            }
        }
    }
    $("#output-text-bulk").click();
}
```